# move constructor error and delegating using a move constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

why does this implementation for the move assignment operator give the error in the attached image

[image]

```
Spreadsheet::Spreadsheet(Spreadsheet&& src) noexcept :Spreadsheet(src.width, src.height) {
    this->cells = src.cells; // Shallow copy of data
    src.cells = nullptr; src.width = 0; src.height = 0; // Reset the source object, because ownership has been moved!

};

Spreadsheet& Spreadsheet::operator=(Spreadsheet&& rhs) noexcept {
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; i++) delete[] cells[i];

    delete[] cells;
    this->width = rhs.width; this->height = rhs.height;
    this->cells = rhs.cells;
    rhs.cells = nullptr; rhs.width = 0; rhs.height = 0;
    return *this;
};
```

I attached the full resources.

the Spreadsheet class definition
SPreadsheet.h

```
#pragma once
#include "SpreadsheetCell.h"



class Spreadsheet
{
public:
    Spreadsheet(size_t, size_t);
    ~Spreadsheet();//1
    void setCellAt(size_t, size_t, const SpreadsheetCell&);
    void verifyCoordinate(size_t, size_t) const;
    void swap(Spreadsheet);
    SpreadsheetCell& getCellAt(size_t, size_t);
    Spreadsheet(const Spreadsheet&);  //copy constructor 2
    Spreadsheet& operator=(const Spreadsheet& rhs);  //assignment operator 3
    Spreadsheet(Spreadsheet&& src) noexcept; // Move constructor 4
    Spreadsheet& operator=(Spreadsheet&& rhs) noexcept; // Move assign 5
private:
    size_t width = 0;
    size_t height = 0;
    SpreadsheetCell** cells = nullptr;
};
```

the Spreadsheet class implementation
Spreadsheet.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Spreadsheet.h"


#include<utility>


Spreadsheet::Spreadsheet(size_t width, size_t height) :width(width), height(height)
{
    cells = new SpreadsheetCell*[width];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height; i++) cells[i] = new SpreadsheetCell[height];
}

void Spreadsheet::verifyCoordinate(size_t x, size_t y) const
{
    (x >= width || y >= height) ? throw std::out_of_range("") : void();// void();
}



void Spreadsheet::setCellAt(size_t x, size_t y, const SpreadsheetCell& cell)
{
    verifyCoordinate(x, y);
    cells[x][y] = cell;
}

SpreadsheetCell& Spreadsheet::getCellAt(size_t x, size_t y) {
    verifyCoordinate(x, y);
    return cells[x][y];
}

Spreadsheet::~Spreadsheet()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        delete[] cells[i];
    };
    delete[] cells;
    cells = nullptr;
}

Spreadsheet::Spreadsheet(const Spreadsheet& src) :Spreadsheet(src.width, src.height) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < height; j++) cells[i][j] = src.cells[i][j];
}
void Spreadsheet::swap(Spreadsheet copyOfRhsDueToBassByVal) {
    std::swap(copyOfRhsDueToBassByVal.width, this->width);
    std::swap(copyOfRhsDueToBassByVal.height, this->height);
    std::swap(copyOfRhsDueToBassByVal.cells, this->cells);
}
Spreadsheet& Spreadsheet::operator=(const Spreadsheet &rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;//we cant use return rhs because it is const but the function header returnning a non-const;
    swap(rhs); return *this;
}

   Spreadsheet::Spreadsheet(Spreadsheet&& src) noexcept :Spreadsheet(src.width, src.height) {
    this->cells = src.cells; // Shallow copy of data
    src.cells = nullptr; src.width = 0; src.height = 0; // Reset the source object, because ownership has been moved!

};

Spreadsheet& Spreadsheet::operator=(Spreadsheet&& rhs) noexcept {
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; i++) delete[] cells[i];

    delete[] cells;
    this->width = rhs.width; this->height = rhs.height;
    this->cells = rhs.cells;
    rhs.cells = nullptr; rhs.width = 0; rhs.height = 0;
    return *this;
};
```

the SpreadsheetCell class definition
SPreadsheetCell.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class SpreadsheetCell
{
public:
    SpreadsheetCell() = default;
    SpreadsheetCell(double initialValue);
    SpreadsheetCell(std::string_view initialValue);
    void setValue(double);
    double getValue() const;

    void setString(std::string_view);
    string getString() const;

private:
    string doubleToString(double) const;
    double stringToDouble(std::string_view) const;

    double value = 0;
};
```

the SpreadsheetCell class implementation

Spreadsheetcell.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SpreadSheetCell.h"



SpreadsheetCell::SpreadsheetCell(double value) :value(value) {};
SpreadsheetCell::SpreadsheetCell(std::string_view strv) { value = stringToDouble(strv); };

void SpreadsheetCell::setValue(double value) { this->value = value; };
double SpreadsheetCell::getValue() const { return value; };

void SpreadsheetCell::setString(std::string_view str) { value = stringToDouble(str); };
string SpreadsheetCell::getString() const { return doubleToString(value); };

string SpreadsheetCell::doubleToString(double inValue) const {
    return to_string(inValue);
}
double SpreadsheetCell::stringToDouble(string_view strv) const {
    return strtod(strv.data(), nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Should `delete[] cells[i];` be `delete cells[i]`? That's the most suspicious-looking line to me without having the full source.

Comment: @Stephano NO the cells def is  `cells = new SpreadsheetCell*[width];
 for (size_t i = 0; i < height; i++) cells[i] = new SpreadsheetCell[height];`And the resources is very long and the code worked well before providing with the move constructor and assignment operator

Comment: We need to see the declaration of whatever the type of `cells` is.  And also the declaration of the `cells` member in `Spreadsheet`.  Please don't make us play guessing games.

Comment: @PaulSanders cells is a ptr of a type `SpreadsheetCell`  and that is the decleration in Spreadsheet.h `SpreadsheetCell** cells = nullptr;`

Comment: @AsmM that loop is wrong. It should be using `i < width` instead of `i < height`.

Comment: @PaulSanders I have attached all of the resources

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think it is a convention only

Comment: Please, Can I know why u dont agree with width and height and why do u say they should be changed

Comment: In which line I did that

Comment: I had allocated an array of a `width` size, then in each element I allocated an array of `height` size by using `for(size_t i=0;i<width;i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several logic bugs in your code:

- your allocating constructor is not looping through the 1st dimension array correctly.  You are allocating an array with `width` number of elements, and then looping through it as if it had `height` number of elements instead. If `width < height`, you exceed the bounds of the array and corrupt memory.  If `width > height`, you don't populate the entire array, leaving it with pointers of indeterminate values.
- Your move constructor is leaking memory.  It delegates to the allocating constructor instead of the default constructor, so a new array is allocated, and then it leaks that array. A move constructor should not be allocating anything at all.
- your `swap()` is not swapping correctly.  The purpose of `swap()` is to exchange the contents of two objects with each other, but your input parameter is being passed by value, so any object passed to it gets copied first, and then you are exchanging with the copied object, not the original object. The original object is unchanged. So you must pass the parameter by reference instead.

Also, a typical and preferable implementation for the move constructor and move assignment operator is to simply swap the contents of the moved-to and moved-from objects. Let the destructor of the moved-from object free any old resources. Don't waste time freeing the old resources before moving the new resources.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#pragma once
#include "SpreadsheetCell.h"

class Spreadsheet
{
public:
    Spreadsheet() = default;
    Spreadsheet(size_t, size_t);
    Spreadsheet(const Spreadsheet &);
    Spreadsheet(Spreadsheet &&) noexcept;
    ~Spreadsheet();

    Spreadsheet& operator=(const Spreadsheet &);
    Spreadsheet& operator=(Spreadsheet &&) noexcept;

    SpreadsheetCell& getCellAt(size_t, size_t);
    void setCellAt(size_t, size_t, const SpreadsheetCell&);

    void swap(Spreadsheet &);

private:
    size_t width = 0;
    size_t height = 0;
    SpreadsheetCell** cells = nullptr;

    void verifyCoordinate(size_t, size_t) const;
};

void swap(Spreadsheet &lhs, Spreadsheet &rhs);
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Spreadsheet.h"
#include <utility> 

Spreadsheet::Spreadsheet() noexcept
    : cells(nullptr), width(0), height(0)
{
}

Spreadsheet::Spreadsheet(int width, int height)
    : cells(nullptr), width(width), height(height)
{
    cells = new SpreadsheetCell*[width];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; ++i)
        cells[i] = new SpreadsheetCell[height];
}

Spreadsheet::Spreadsheet(const Spreadsheet &src)
    : Spreadsheet(src.width, src.height)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < height; ++j)
            cells[i][j] = src.cells[i][j];
}

Spreadsheet::Spreadsheet(Spreadsheet &&src) noexcept
    : Spreadsheet()
{
    src.swap(*this);
}

Spreadsheet::~Spreadsheet()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; ++i)
        delete[] cells[i];
    delete[] cells;
}

Spreadsheet& Spreadsheet::operator=(const Spreadsheet &rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
        Spreadsheet(rhs).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

Spreadsheet& Spreadsheet::operator=(Spreadsheet &&rhs) noexcept
{
    rhs.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

SpreadsheetCell& Spreadsheet::getCellAt(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    verifyCoordinate(x, y);
    return cells[x][y];
}

void Spreadsheet::setCellAt(size_t x, size_t y, const SpreadsheetCell& cell)
{
    verifyCoordinate(x, y);
    cells[x][y] = cell;
}

void Spreadsheet::swap(Spreadsheet &other)
{
    std::swap(cells, other.cells);
    std::swap(width, other.width);
    std::swap(height, other.height);
}

void Spreadsheet::verifyCoordinate(size_t x, size_t y) const
{
    if (x >= width || y >= height)
        throw std::out_of_range("");
}

void swap(Spreadsheet &lhs, Spreadsheet &rhs)
{
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}
```

That being said, this code can be greatly simplified if you use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays:

```
#pragma once
#include "SpreadsheetCell.h"
#include <vector>

class Spreadsheet
{
public:
    Spreadsheet() = default;
    Spreadsheet(size_t, size_t);
    Spreadsheet(const Spreadsheet &) = default;
    Spreadsheet(Spreadsheet &&) noexcept = default;

    Spreadsheet& operator=(const Spreadsheet &) = default;
    Spreadsheet& operator=(Spreadsheet &&) noexcept = default;

    SpreadsheetCell& getCellAt(size_t, size_t);
    void setCellAt(size_t, size_t, const SpreadsheetCell&);

    void swap(Spreadsheet &);

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<SpreadsheetCell>> cells;
};

void swap(Spreadsheet &lhs, Spreadsheet &rhs);
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Spreadsheet.h"
#include <utility>

Spreadsheet::Spreadsheet(int width, int height)
{
    cells.resize(width);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; ++i)
        cells[i].resize(height);
}

SpreadsheetCell& Spreadsheet::getCellAt(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    return cells.at(x).at(y);
}

void Spreadsheet::setCellAt(size_t x, size_t y, const SpreadsheetCell& cell)
{
    cells.at(x).at(y) = cell;
}

void Spreadsheet::swap(Spreadsheet &other)
{
    std::swap(cells, other.cells);
}

void swap(Spreadsheet &lhs, Spreadsheet &rhs)
{
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}
```

Comment: I wanna know the cause of the error.I can change the code. Shouldn't we  consider the overheading in the case of large objects(it is not my case)

Comment: @AsmM you have several logic bugs in your code

Comment: I am waiting to know them

Comment: @AsmM see my other comments

Comment: Yes u r right. I see it now thanks.I used height twice and one of them was instead of width.

Comment: But I don't comply with your `swap()` input parameter is declared incorrectly. It needs to be passed by reference, not by value. especially in my case

Comment: @AsmM Is there something about `void swap(Spreadsheet &);` that I am missing?

Comment: @AsmM do you understand the difference between passing a parameter by value vs by reference? Do you understand what `swap()` is *supposed* to do? Your `swap()` makes a copy and then swaps with the copy, not the original. `swap()` needs to swap with the original instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau off course, I know the difference. I cannot use the original because if it is used it will be changed by swapping but by using the copy it is not needed so no problem

Comment: these are the functions I ment `void Spreadsheet::swap(Spreadsheet copyOfRhsDueToBassByVal) {
    std::swap(copyOfRhsDueToBassByVal.width, this->width);
    std::swap(copyOfRhsDueToBassByVal.height, this->height);
    std::swap(copyOfRhsDueToBassByVal.cells, this->cells);
}
Spreadsheet& Spreadsheet::operator=(const Spreadsheet &rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;//we cant use return rhs because it is const but the function header returnning a non-const;
    swap(rhs); return *this;
}
`

Comment: @AsmM the original object is *SUPPOSED* to be changed by `swap`, otherwise `swap` is useless. The way you implemented your copy assignment operator via an improper `swap` is wrong, and it prevents you from using `swap` in other operations it would be useful for. The code in my answer has a proper `swap` and usage. And BTW, your reasoning for "can't return rhs" is incorrect. Not returning `rhs` has nothing to do with `const`. Operators that modify an object on the left side must return that same object. This is to facilitate chaining operations together.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks a lot